# saying thanks to someone answering your email ASAP who is important for you

Tags: expressions, idioms, politeness

Which of these sentences sounds more american?
and which sounds more polite against who is important for you like a professor or boss?

first:

> Thanks for your prompt response

second:

> Thanks for your quick answer

third:

> Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: **Promptness** is what you want to emphasize. It speaks about the time between a request and its response or between an expected event and the actual event.  Whether a reply is *fast* or an answer is *quick* is irrelevant. You don't care how fast the reply moved as it was delivered; you care about the delay between request and response delivery. But to answer your question: they are all American, and none is more so than the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would say;

> Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.

This is casual but still serious. It is American and respectful.