# Difference between promptness and promptitude

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Seeing [this EL&U question: *'saying thanks to someone answering your email ASAP who is important for you'*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197113/saying-thanks-to-someone-answering-your-email-asap-who-is-important-for-you), the first word that came to my mind was [*promptitude*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/promptitude) which, as the definition states, can convey both punctuality and non-delay-ness(immediate-ness)

So I thought this would be a good answer for said question

> thank you for your *promptitude*

But after googling the subject (to see if this is an american expression as required by the OP), I stumbled upon the word [*promptness*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/promptness) which seems to convey the same meanings of punctuality and non-delay-ness[(and to be a lot more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thank+you+for+your+promptitude%2Cthank+you+for+your+promptness&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthank%20you%20for%20your%20promptness%3B%2Cc0) [than my first *frenchy* choice](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promptitude%2C+promptness&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromptitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpromptness%3B%2Cc0)).  So, I thought that one could equally/better propose

> thank you for your *promptness*

Now, I have no problem recognizing *promptness* as an equally/more valid word for the same usage. But, at the same time, my problem lies precisely there: it is too much *an equally valid word for the same usage*, because when I went hunting for small nuances between the two words(because someone on EL&U/ELL once said that synonyms usually denote of different connotations) I couldn't find any.. I am further *appalled* by the fact that they *stem from the same root*.

Yes, the question:

Am I wrong in :

1. assuming that promptitude & promptness have no distinct connotations (in this context particularly)?
2. thinking that perfect synonyms are something of a rarity?
3. thinking that *same-root* perfect synonyms are something of a rarity?
4. a combination of 1., 2., 3. and some other speculation of mine?

Why? (added for the charmingly joking nature of EL&Uers)

---

### Edit

After receiving some comments and one answer I have to add:

Again, I have no problem recognizing *promptness* as an equally/**more** valid word for the same usage.

But it seems to me that we have these two words from the same root that mean the same thing. How come? Is it just because one is becoming obsolete and that's how words die - another one comes and slowly but steadily takes its place? or is it something different?

Comment: If it helps, Merriam-Webster gives one sense of "*promptitude*" as the **habit** of being prompt; a sense it denies to  "*promptness*". Futhermore, the OED has *two* senses for "*promptitude*", and only one for "*promptness*". So, aside from the definition which makes them synonyms, "*promptitude*" **also** means "*A prompting, an impulse; an inclination.*" (which is marked with *Obs.*, unfortunately).

Comment: @Dan: The noun "promptness" itself could be used in the sense of something habitual. Depends on the context. If your child's teacher wants to talk to you about the kid's *tardiness*, you would likely suppose there to be a pattern of that behavior in evidence.

Comment: @Mina Huh, I thought I checked that and didn't see the same meaning. Oh well.  That said, OneLook does provide *[two meanings](http://www.onelook.com/?w=promptitude&ls=a)* for *-ness* and *[only one](http://www.onelook.com/?w=promptness)* for *-itude* (which is actually the opposite of what I found in the OED).

Comment: @DanBron Confusing, isn't it?

Comment: From Google Books... [*Thank you for your promptness*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):29200 results, [*Thank you for your promptitude*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptitude%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):217 results. And most of the latter are well over a century old. Any supposed difference in "meaning" is insignificant compared to the fact of using dated/unusual words, which is bound to stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @Mina, It is indeed. I'm leaning towards "they're synonyms".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmmm.. but [promptness - 1,310,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22promptness%22) and [promptitude - 1,880,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptitude%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22promptitude%22) get the reverse treatment

Comment: @Mina: Raw figures for single words don't necessarily tell us much. Per my first link, the difference *for your exact context* is 100:1 in favour of *promptness*, even without taking account of usage changing over time. For more on that "change over time", consider [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+promptitude%2Cyour+promptness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20promptitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20promptness%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I already gave a similar ngram in my answer, but what I failed to do is correctly interpret it. So do you mean that _promptitude_ is _dying_ and my question is not _correct_ as a result?

Comment: @Mina: Not at all - I think your question is perfectly "correct" for this site. I seriously doubt you could establish any difference between the two words simply by consulting dictionaries, since they're unlikely to give any explicit clues. If you knew what you were looking for, you could maybe derive a hint from the fact that the definition for *promptitude* includes the word *promptness*, but not the other way around. But any native speaker who ever sends formal business letters/emails will know which word they use and expect to read, so an "unequivocally correct" answer is realistic here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Correct me if I'm wrong, but The Farlex definition of _promptitude_ I gave doesn't include _promptness_, it only cites it as a synonym. Both the [OneLook dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=promptitude&ls=a) and the [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/promptitude) do the same.

Comment: @Mina: I should have said - that was from OED, which is the only one I looked at (though I've just checked, and the same applies to [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promptitude)). But gimmie a break! I'm struggling to justify "this is a good question for ELU", given that practically every native speaker knows you normally thank someone for their *promptness* (not *promptitude*, a word many will never have encountered). We have ELL for people who aren't familiar with "English as she is spoke".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get [46](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptness%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=80) and [34](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptitude%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptitude%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=30) in Google Books, once I page to the end.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure where all this is going. Is anyone seriously suggesting I'm mistaken in saying that *promptitude* is a relatively dated/unusual word in OP's context? Obviously Google Books has limitations, but just check the *dates* on those 80 instances we can actually see. Incidentally, I'd invariably use *prompt **reply*** or ***response*** anyway, and so I believe would most. The estimated results for *"thank you for your prompt reply"* are less than *promptness*, but there are actually far more of them (though it just gets "stuck" on page 11 of the results for me).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, "...prompt reply" shows [135](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+promptness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22thank+you+for+your+prompt+reply%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=150). The dates are much older on the 34 instances of Promptitude, but oddly, only the first 23 of the 46 citations of Promptness actually contains the phrase when you follow them. And only the first 37 of the 135 for Prompt Reply actually contains the phrase. I'm a bit bewildered, and am probably further off-track than you are...

Comment: @Daniel: My starting point is that I already know *promptitude* is the rarer and more dated term, so it's just a matter of finding appropriate ways to back that up. If you compare the dates on the (est. 49) results for [*qualities such as **promptness***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qualities+such+as+promptness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) with just 8 for ***...promptitude***, you get the same story.

Comment: Yes, with this I agree. Google's penchant for grossly inflating its stated result count is merely tangential. I wish there was a Stack Exchange site for which the question would be on-topic...

Comment: Synonyms with different distributions (frequency of use in otherwise identical sentences) are by definition not 'perfect synonyms'. Which therefore almost certainly don't exist. // 'Promptitude' connotes a farcical register.

Answer (score 9):

I have to say that, in British English, I cannot recall ever having seen 'promptitude' used in any context.

In the example situation quoted it would be normal to say 'thank you for your promptness in replying' or, more likely, 'thank you for your prompt reply.'

Comment: Yeah, and if I got an email using the word "promptitude", I would think the writer was either a pompous ass or someone not familiar with English. It's an email!

Comment: I really have to remember this next time I write an email.

Comment: But it seems [this guy](http://www.londontranslations.co.uk/testimonials/market-research/ipsos-interactive/) and [Marc from Long Beach here](http://www.california-shortsale.com/testimonials/) didn't get the memo.

Comment: @Tony Balmforth You seem to say that the answer to 1. is 'Yes, there is a huge difference: One is idiomatic, the other is not _at all_ because, as a native speaker, I have never heard of it' It is a perfectly valid argument for me +1

Comment: But this doesn't fully answer my question: How come we have now two words from the same root in English that convey the exact same meaning?

Comment: @Mina Apologies for delay in commenting. I'm not sure I have enough formal grammar expertise to answer with certainty. I was simply expressing the view that I had never heard the word 'promptitude' used and that, whilst it might be understood, it would sound slightly comical to a Br English user. Hey ho!

Comment: @TonyBalmforth Well, thank you for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promptness%2Cprompitude&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

The examples of "prompitude" are almost exclusively from historical quotes

A picture is worth a 1,000 words:

[image]